# Unable to output all JSON items via Jquery each while using Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

i am trying to fetch some json data into backbone collection and than trying to display on the screen when the view is rendered.
the issue is that i am not able to iterate through all the companies listed in json data on a click, even though they show on console.log. The only output i am getting is just the first company listed in json data.  i tried using each function but not much success.

```
 <div class="test">Click</div>

 <div class="new_test"></div> 

 <script>
 var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
 var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: myModel,
 url : "myjson.json",
 parse : function(response){
 return response.employees;  
 } 
 })

 var jobs = new myCollection();

 var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

 el:'body',

 initialize : function(){

 jobs.fetch();
 this.render();
 },
 events:{
     'click div.test':'render'
},
render : function(){

jobs.each(function(myModel){
var _comp = myModel.get('company');
$('div.new_test').html(_comp);

console.log(_comp);
return this;
})
}
})
var yourView = new myView();


// json Data

{
"employees": [
     { "company":"ford" , "Type":"Doe" }, 
     { "company":"jaguar" , "Type":"Smith" }, 
     { "company":"merceded" , "Type":"Jones" }
             ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of this line

```
$('div.new_test').html(_comp);
```

Which overwrites the `HTML`

You need to append the text instead .. You can use the `append` method instead

```
$('div.new_test').append(_comp);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hahcV/)**